# Error loading file in Sage

Tags: sage

I am trying to use Sage on a mac and am not particularly computer savvy (e.g. I still haven't figured out what I am meant to do with `PATH` and find the installation documentation a bit forbidding). I am running sage from the command line from a particular folder which contains a file "test.sage" but when I put 'load("`test.sage`")' I get the following error message:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 load("test.sage")

/Applications/SageMath/src/sage/structure/sage_object.pyx in sage.structure.sage_object.load (/Applications/SageMath/src/build/cythonized/sage/structure/sage_object.c:11186)()

```
 if sage.repl.load.is_loadable_filename(filename):
     sage.repl.load.load(filename, globals())
     return
```

/Applications/SageMath/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/repl/load.pyc in load(filename, globals, attach)

```
 if attach:
      add_attached_file(fpath)
      exec(preparse_file(open(fpath).read()) + "\n", globals)
 elif ext == '.spyx' or ext == '.pyx':
     if attach:
```

Error message

```
TypeError: expected string without null bytes"
```

Earlier on I was trying the same thing and getting the message:
"IOError('did not find file %r to load or attach'"

I wonder if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong or might try to fix the problem?